# Spring Boot + RabbitMQ messages lost on delayed exchange

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using spring boot `convertAndSend()` to publish a message on a delayed exchange but the message is never being published on the queue and there isn't any exception being thrown

Comment: Check if the message goes into the delayed exchange. You can see this in the management interface -> Exchanges. You can also check the "unrouted dropped"-metric and see if it can't be routed.

Comment: Fro some reason since I am using delayed exchange all the messages are being marked as unrouted. On side not, I am not losing the messages on each case, I have a retry mechanism which re-queues the message with a new number of attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is never being published on the queue and there isn't any exception being thrown

When a system wants to communicate via a message broker the developer needs a clear understanding of the delivery semantics. At first one needs to know if and how often a message will be delivered to the broker (and potential consumers):

1. At most once – the message is delivered at most once but also not at all.
2. At least once – the message guaranteed to be delivered but can be delivered multiple times.
3. Exactly once – the message is guaranteed to be delivered exactly once.

The reasons why your messages are lost is because probably you are using `at most once` semantics.

You can configure `at least once` delivery semantics if you follow this [guide](https://synyx.de/blog/implementing-at-least-once-delivery-with-rabbitmq-and-springs-rabbittemplate/)

Does this solve your problem ? Tell me in the comments.

Comment: Not really I added the publisher confirm and the publisher return but I am still losing messages without any error